# TypeError: method takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python

Частенько в стандартной библиотеке встречаются функции или методы, выбрасывающие такое исключение, если предоставить им именованный аргумент. Пару примеров:

```
d = {"yo": "value"}

print(d.get("key", default="DEFAULT_VALUE"))

import datetime
fmt = "%d-%m-%y"

print(datetime.datetime.strptime("23-08-2016", format=fmt))
```

Известно, как эту проблему решить - не предоставлять именованных аргументов. Однако, не совсем понятно откуда растут ноги у этой проблемы, потому что с обыкновенными функциями, очевидно, все в порядке:

```
def ordinary_func(operand1, operand2):
    return operand1 * operand2

print(ordinary_func(operand1=5, operand2=8))
```

Есть предположение, что какие-то функции и методы вызывают напрямую функции на C, но этот факт не проясняет вопроса. К тому же в этом случае все функции по этому критерию будут разделены на 2 части - которым можно предоставить именованные аргументы (написанные на чистом Python) и которым нельзя (написанные на C). Это странный и печальный факт, ибо мне надо держать в голове, кому можно предоставлять именованный аргумент, а кому нельзя и нет гарантии, что однажды такое исключение не будет правильно обработано. Да и выходом тогда может стать не использовать именованные аргументы вообще, чтобы не ходить по минному полю.

Comment: Сталкивался с подобным поведением, но как-то не задумывался что что-то тут не так. Мое предположение: Python просто не знает имен аргументов методов встроенных классов, поэтому и передать в них аргументы по имени нельзя. Возможно, это какая-то оптимизация.

Comment: @insolor вероятнее всего потому что в си нет именованных аргументов

Answer (score 3):

Откуда ноги растут - всегда можно посмотреть в [исходниках самого cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/methodobject.c#L102). Это действительно обрабатывается сишными вызовами. Там же можно увидеть и сообщения исключений о том, что функция принимает один аргумент или функция не принимает аргументов вовсе.

> будут разделены на 2 части - которым можно предоставить именованные аргументы (написанные на чистом Python) и которым нельзя (написанные на C)

Ну вообще вы и в python можете написать функцию, которая принимает только именованные аргументы

```
>>> def bar(**kwargs):
...     print(kwargs)
... 
>>> bar(1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

.. и даже только неименованные

```
>>> def foo(*args):
...     print(args)
... 
>>> foo(a=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

Ну а чтобы не путаться когда какие аргументы использовать для вас в python написана превосходная справка - как онлайн, так и в виде `docstrings`:

```
>>> d = {"yo": "value"}
>>> print(d.get.__doc__)
D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
```